# pseudorandom number generation from truncated normal distribution in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran, normal-distribution

I am trying to draw pseudo random numbers from a left-truncated normal distribution using FORTRAN. I want the function  to return values with the same dimension as inputs:

FUNCTION (MU, SIGMA) ; mu=N x 1 and SIGMA = N X 1

Can someone help please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What did *you* try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use the GNU Scientific Library and the Fortran interface thereto: http://www.lrz.de/services/software/mathematik/gsl/fortran/.  The GSL has a random normal generator.  Reject and try again if the number is on the wrong side.  The easiest method is to put it all in a loop and use the underlying random number generator in a serial manner.  Multi-threaded random numbers are subtle to get right.